# I want to get 'User Access and Control management system' into two separate lines. how should do?

Tags: powershell

```
{
    id: uniqueId(),
    title: 'User Access and Control management system',
    icon: FaUsers,
    href: '/systems/userAccess/',
    children: [
      {
        id: uniqueId(),
        title: 'System Access',
        icon: IconPoint,
        href: '/systems/userAccess/UserAccess',
      },
    ],
  },
```

want to get that title into two separate lines. I have tried with different solutions. but still didn't success.

Comment: It is a string so add '\n' :  'User Access and \nControl Management system'

Comment: I tried it so many times. But still not work

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and also the errormessages if you received any.